# How does sample_weight compare to class_weight in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to use [sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) on an imbalanced classification problem. I intend to optimize for [Area Under the Receiver Operating Characteristic Curve (ROC AUC)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html). For this I would like to reweight my classes to make the small class more important to the classifier.

This would normally be done (in [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) for example) by setting class_weight = “balanced” but there is no such parameter in the GradientBoostingClassifier.

The documentation says:

**The “balanced” mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust weights inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data as n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))**

If y_train is my dataframe of my target with elements in {0,1}, then the documentation implies that this should reproduce the same as class_weight = “balanced”

```
sample_weight = y_train.shape[0]/(2*np.bincount(y_train))
clf = ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier(**params)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train,sample_weight = sample_weight[y_train.values])
```

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `class_weight.compute_sample_weight` utility in scikit-learn. 
For example:

```
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_sample_weight
y = [1,1,1,1,0,0,1]
compute_sample_weight(class_weight='balanced', y=y)
```

Output:

```
array([ 0.7 ,  0.7 ,  0.7 ,  0.7 ,  1.75,  1.75,  0.7 ])
```

You can use this as input to the `sample_weight` keyword.

Comment: Thank you, this produces the same array as my code but it is much clearer and cleaner.

Comment: What if some of the classes are extremely rare, and a high value (for example, 3000) occurs for a sample weight? Should such values be smoothed somehow, or just use them directly?